# Error while Deploying WAR in WebSphere using ANT

Tags: deployment, websphere, ear

We are trying to checkout, build  and deploy EAR files ( IBM Integration Designer developed Mediation Modules.. but mostly similar to Java EAR files ). While deploying to WAS ND I am getting the below error...

```
[wsadmin] WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "C:\Users\INSTAL~2\AppData\Local\Temp\wsant1588202279705404612jacl"; exception information: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7132E: Application install for C:\Ant_Automation\ESB\MMCheckout\KY_SF1520_CPRServices_MMApplication\KY_SF1520_CPRServices_MM.ear failed: see previous messages for details.

[wsadmin] WASX7341W: No "save" was performed before the interactive scripting session exited; configuration changes will not be saved.

BUILD FAILED

C:\Ant_Automation\ESB\build.xml:124: Java returned: 105

Total time: 1 minute 53 seconds
```

I think we have to save the configuration after deployment in a ND deployment, but I am not sure how we can save using ANT.

***DMGR System log***

```
[28-06-16 16:43:13:572 CEST] 000003ef InstallSchedu I   ADMA5016I: Installation of KY_SF1520_CPRServices_MMApp started.
[28-06-16 16:43:14:384 CEST] 000003ef Configuration I com.ibm.bpm.config.spi.ConfigurationSpi getDeploymentEnvironment Effective deployment target is WebSphere:cell=KYDevBMP02Cell01,node=KYDevBMP02CellManager01,server=dmgr
[28-06-16 16:43:14:400 CEST] 000003ef Configuration I com.ibm.bpm.config.spi.ConfigurationSpi getDeploymentEnvironment Effective deployment target is WebSphere:cell=KYDevBMP02Cell01,node=KYDevBMP02CellManager01,server=dmgr
[28-06-16 16:43:14:493 CEST] 000003ef WBIAAbstractT I com.ibm.ws.wbia.deployment.WBIAAbstractTask performTask CWLRD0101I: No WebSphere Business Integration Adapter files are found in the application KY_SF1520_CPRServices_MMApp.
[28-06-16 16:43:15:134 CEST] 000003ef Configuration I com.ibm.bpm.config.spi.ConfigurationSpi getDeploymentEnvironment Effective deployment target is WebSphere:cell=KYDevBMP02Cell01,node=KYDevBMP02CellManager01,server=dmgr
[28-06-16 16:43:15:149 CEST] 000003ef InstallSchedu I   ADMA5014E: The installation of application KY_SF1520_CPRServices_MMApp failed.
```

Comment: Few comments: 1) Mediation modules created in IID are for BPM/WPS NOT WAS ND. If you have only WAS ND, they will fail anyway. 2) Error already indicates: `see previous messages for details.` - you didnt provide any details. 3) You didn't provide your ant script so it is hard to say if you are using `WsAdmin` task or `wsInstallApp`. If the former then you need to include `AdminConfig.save()` in the script.

Comment: I am installing in IBM BPM Process Server only, it has the WAS ND in the bottom.
previous message dont have any error details

Comment: i am using wsInstallApp. how i can save the config while using this?? or is is not required?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCKBL_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/ant/tasks/package-frame.html

Comment: build file and full log. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0By650YeW4BmCVDBiaGw0QURCWTQ&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save if you are using , check this link for Ant script example [Using Ant scripts for testing in headless WebSphere Business Process Manager](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSV2LR/com.ibm.wbpm.wid.admin.doc/topics/tcfgant.html)

You have to look for error details either in the Ant console output or server SystemOut.log.

Look at your messages:

```
Effective deployment target is WebSphere:cell=KYDevBMP02Cell01,node=KYDevBMP02CellManager01,server=dmgr
```

This is not correct, you are installing application to either Cluster of some server, but for sure not DeploymentManager.

You have to provide `options` to your `wsInstallApp` task that will define target. See `AdminApp.install` [command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.soafep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_callappinstall.html) for details.

Comment: i dont find anything in ANT console output. i have updated the DMGR systemout log in the question. No clue.. please help.

Comment: build file and full log: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0By650YeW4BmCVDBiaGw0QURCWTQ&usp=sharing

Comment: i tried with this
options="-usedefaultbindings -target WebSphere:cell=KYDevBMP02Cell01,cluster=ProcessServerDB.SingleCluster"

after this the operation is getting completed successful.. but i am getting a very new errors...

attached the new log in the google drive path.

Comment: Hi, instead of the target try: `-cluster ProcessServerDB.SingleCluster`

Comment: Also try to install that app simply using web admin console and see if it installs correctly.